# Get select option value from forms using jquery created dynamically in loop

Tags: jquery, html, forms, dynamic, drop-down-menu

This is my first question here so please forgive me if I have violated any of the rules. This is more specifically a jquery related question and my knowledge with jquery is limited.

I am trying to get the value of a SELECT element from the forms created dynamically in FOR loop. The problem is while I am able to get the value for the first form, it is returning the same value for next set of forms.

For example, using FOR loop, I am generating 5 dynamic forms with multiple hidden input fields, one select field ( values are static such as 1,2,3 etc) and a submit button. There is no problem in fetching values of hidden input fields for different forms using jquery attr() function. But when I apply this attr() function for SELECT field, it works for the first form only. All the subsequent forms returns the same value as by the first form.

```
var value= $('option:selected', '.select-class').attr('data-value');
```

Please suggest me how do I get value of SELECT field for multiple forms inside a loop.

Thanks

EDIT: Below I have pasted the whole code. It's been modified from the original one but the question is still the same. You can see now I am sending data using anchor tag ( instead of button ) and while loop ( instead of for loop now ). Please have a look a the code.

```
<?php while($fetch=$query->fetch()) { ?>
      <select class="form-control sel_qty" name="product_qty" >                                            
             <option value="1" data-qty="1">1</option>
             <option value="2" data-qty="2">2</option>
             <option value="3" data-qty="3">3</option>
             <option value="4" data-qty="4">4</option>
             <option value="5" data-qty="5">5</option>                                            
       </select>
       <a href='#' class="btn btn-primary cart_submit" 
            data-code="<?php echo $fetch['product_code']; ?>" 
            data-title="<?php echo $fetch['title']; ?>" 
            data-price="<?php echo $fetch['price']; ?>" 
            data-url="<?php echo $fetch['url']; ?>" > 
        Submit 
        </a>
<?php } ?>
```

Using jquery I am able to get value of data attributes of each anchor tag in the while loop in the following way:

```
                   var product_code= $(this).attr("data-code");
                   var product_title= $(this).attr("data-title");
                   var product_price= $(this).attr("data-price");
                   var product_url= $(this).attr("data-url");
```

But how do I get the value of each select element inside the while loop. I am able to get value for only first select element, and not the subsequent ones.

```
                 var value= $('option:selected', '.sel_qty').attr('data-qty');
```

This above code is getting values of only first select element available in the loop

Comment: You need to make loop again for fetching all options values. For loop on forms.

Comment: can you show the code (Full)

Answer (score 0):

Based on the small amount of info and code you have supplied, if the code you posted is the code inside your loop, your problem is not the dynamically created forms, but the reference inside the loop you are using is not Relative.
Without know what you are doing, you could do something like:

```
$('form').each(function(){
    var form = $(this);
    var value= form.find('option:selected', '.select-class').attr('data-value');
    ...
})
```